# Is there any way to animate sprites using just the logic bricks in the Blender Game Engine?

Tags: game-engine

Is there any way possible to animate sprites using just the logic bricks in Blender Game? I saw a video of this, but there wasn't much to build off of. The game I'm making involves 2D sprites that animate.

If possible, will a visual example be provided. If not, I'll take any response.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody seems to answer i'll try.

There are built-in ways to animate sprites from a spritesheet
using the texture properties. Unfortunately this feature is broken in some versions.

There is a python script that can do it.

A rather uncommon way that worked well for me is to put each
frame of your animation on a separate plane(square mesh) and trigger a loop
in "edit object-->change mesh"-actuator with numeric property counter.

Comment: A bit more of a description of the texture coordinate method and a link to the python script would be great.